# Is there a way to power a GPU only by external supply?

Tags: power-supply, pcie, gpu

Actually I don't think so, because I think different components of the GPU are powered by only one of the two sources.

Comment: In theory yes, but I bet the power sequencing with the rest of the computer is probably going to be a big issue , so no.

Comment: How do you define the "external supply"? Do you mean the +12V ATX connector and no +12V on PCIe connector? Or no +12 and no +3v3 on the connector? Something different altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get external PCIe enclosures that power the GPU using an external supply.  You could also in principle connect the GPU power connectors to an external supply, although I wouldn't recommend doing this.